# Xcode Unexpected @ error

Tags: objective-c

I have tried everything to try and fix it I read throughout the other similar questions but nothing worked.

```
#import "ViewController.h"
//sound
@implementation SoundappViewController
-(IBAction)play; {
CFBundleRef mainBundle = CFBundleGetMainBundle();
CFURLRef soundFileURLRef;
soundFileURLRef = CFBundleCopyResourceURL(mainBundle, (CFStringRef) @"app 3", CFSTR ("m4a"), NULL);
   UInt32 (soundID);
   AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID(soundFileURLRef, &soundID);
   AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(soundID);
    @end              // Here i get the error Unexpected @ in program
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you included the exact error message that you're receiving, but I'm going to guess the error is due the lack of closing brace `}` for the IBAction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Remove ';' in method header line
- You're missin '}' in the end of your method (right before @end)